# Convert Arraylist into a 2d Array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I Basically wanted to take an input and store it into a 2D Array called mat with a 3x3 size

so i tried taking an input string, convert them into char and then sotring them in an array list and this is what i wrote so far.

```
System.out.println("Enter Message");
Scanner Scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
String plaintext = Scanner1.next();
int counter = 0;
// will get chars till the end of input length
while(plaintext.length() > 0){
    char text = plaintext.charAt(counter);
    counter++;
    ArrayList mylist = new ArrayList();
    mylist.add(text);
    System.out.println(mylist);          // chars of string
}
```

How can I convert this `List` into A 2D

I tried something else also i tried using split like this

```
System.out.println("Enter Message");
Scanner Scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
String plaintext = Scanner1.next();

String[] parts = plaintext.split("");

for (int i=1; i<=3; i++){
     System.out.println(parts[i]);
}
```

This gives me
    H
    e
    l

Sorted as 1 row with 3 columns
The output of the Arraylist is something like this

```
[H]
[e]
[l]
[l]
[o]
```

I would like a 2D array like this:

```
[H][e][l];
[l][o][w];
[x][y][z];
```

or

```
H e l;
l o w;
x y z;
```

I just need to convert my input string into the 2d form of array and I've been trying a lot I cant get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
 String[][] parts = new String[3][3];

 // then do this in your loop instead of adding to the list
 parts[count/3][count%3] = text;
```

However you also have other issues. In your first loop, the length will always be > 0 and you will keep getting chars until you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Consider doing a for loop instead.

Comment: parts[count/3][count%3] = text;
it said i cant convert from char to string , im not sure what that meant